# MySQL 'Group By' messes up virtual column count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select distinct rows within my SQL table, however I'm not having luck in labeling the returned  rows appropriately using the code below:

```
    SELECT  @row:=@row+1 as rank,
            a.id,
            a.name
    FROM table a, 
    ( SELECT  @row:=0) b
    GROUP BY  a.id
    ORDER BY  a.name ASC
```

This query will return the following:

```
| RANK |   ID    |   NAME
--------------------------
   2   |  4483   |  Bob 
   8   |  9453   |  Joe
   10  |  4543   |  Maurice
```

What I want it to return is this, however:

```
| RANK |   ID    |   NAME
--------------------------
   1   |  4483   |  Bob 
   2   |  9453   |  Joe
   3   |  4543   |  Maurice
```

Would it be more appropriate for me to use a DISTINCT query for a query of this magnitude?

Comment: you'd need to wrap your grouped query with ANOTHER query that does the @row++ stuff. you are getting proper results, but the group by is "eliminating" your rows because they're members of the same grouping.

Comment: Why can't you accumulate the rank as you iterate the resultset in PHP?

Comment: Your code works for me in a fiddle - perhaps my data doesn't match yours. Feel free to alter the fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7973a/2

Comment: @Turophile I'm using GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates from the code, as such, if there were duplicate ID's within the Table, the Rank would go 1,2,5 if there were 3 entries of the user "Joe" with the ID "9453", which is the case when I play around with that fiddle unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Marc B's solution, I decided to wrap my query with another one however instead I decided to Select **DISTINCT** columns rather than grouping them which would remove my margin of error, by using this code

```
SELECT @row:=@row+1 as rank, a.id, a.name FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT id, name 
FROM Table1
) a, (SELECT @row:=0) b


ORDER BY a.name ASC
```